# customized images and text

Tags: beamer, graphics, itemize

I'm working on beamer presentation. I want to have a particular layout on a slide: 
its an itemized list with two items; after the first item (with some text), the second item has some text to the left and couple of images one below the other on the right-hand side.

How can I achieve this? Appreciate any help.

Comment: 243 rep. points witout a MWE? Please add what you tried so far.

Comment: In addition to providing a MWE, can you please add a sketch how the layout should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % for valign=t in includegraphics
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text

\item
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. 
  \end{minipage}\quad
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=t]{example-image-a}

    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I tried with dividing the slide into three columns.